# How manually gain permissions for specific actions in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, custom-function

When attempting to run this code, I get an error:

> You do not have permission to call getFiles (line 22).

I am using it as a custom function. How do I gain the necessary permissions in order to call getFiles.

Line of code causing the error: **var files = DriveApp.getFiles();**

```
/**
This is only a test
**/
function getLonnie(data) {
      var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log("hello");
  var myArray = [];
  var numTimesLonnie = 0;
  for(var row = 0; row<data.length; row++){
    for(var col = 0; col<data[0].length; col++){
      if((data[row][col]) === "Lonnie"|| (data[row][col]) === "Lonnie Gerol"){
      numTimesLonnie++;
        myArray.push(data[row][col])
        //sSheet.getRange(row, col).setBackground("red");

      }
    }

  }
   // Generate a log, then email it to the person who ran the script.
   var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
   Logger.log(files.next().getName());
 }
 var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 var subject = 'A list of files in your Google Drive';
 var body = Logger.getLog();
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);


  return numTimesLonnie;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? Are you using it as a custom function or using simple trigger?

Comment: @Rubén I am using it as a custom function

Comment: Custom functions can't use getFiles or any other method that requires permissions to run.

Comment: @Rubén what is an alternative to creating a custom function?

Comment: "All others" with exception of simple triggers :)

Comment: @Rubén Where can I find documentation on other types of functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164106/discussion-between-ruben-and-lontronix).